# How to format date in Query Statement Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using php with Mysql and I need to run a specific query when user selects month and year in a date_field.
This query returns all records created by the month/year selected by user and I don't want relate days in a clause where inside the select.
Since I need only records from month/year select, is there any ways how can I define inside the select only month/year?

Here is my Mysql statement with variable selected by user
There are two tables related with inner join so I can 'grab' records with Date:

```
$quer_mesano = "Select b.name AS Canal                                  
                                from canal_canalvenda b
                                inner join meta_meta c On  c.canal_canalvenda_id_c = b.id
                                And c.deleted = 0
                                where c.periodo = '$month_year' //Here is the date value I just need to put in month/year
                                And b.deleted = 0
                                Group by Canal order by 1";
```

Can any one help me?

Comment: In your schema, how is column c.periodo defined? what format is $month_year in, can you give an example?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html, `date_format()` in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DATE_FORMAT() you can use as shown below

```
$quer_mesano = "Select b.name AS Canal                                  
                            from canal_canalvenda b
                            inner join meta_meta c On  c.canal_canalvenda_id_c = b.id
                            And c.deleted = 0
                            where DATE_FORMAT( c.periodo, '%Y/%m' ) = '$month_year'
                            And b.deleted = 0
                            Group by Canal order by 1";
```

For month you have different types -
%M  Month name
%m  Month, numeric (00-12)
and for year -
%Y  Year, four digits
%y  Year, two digits

Answer (score 3):

This is very easy. Use DATE_FORMAT. Just change the Sql statement like this:

```
$quer_mesano = "Select b.name AS Canal                                  
                            from canal_canalvenda b
                            inner join meta_meta c On  c.canal_canalvenda_id_c = b.id
                            And c.deleted = 0
                            where DATE_FORMAT( c.periodo, '%Y-%m' ) = '$month_year' //Just put DATE_FORMAT
                            And b.deleted = 0
                            Group by Canal order by 1";
```

Comment: This won't use any index you happen to have defined on `meta_meta.periodo`.  If your performance depends on that, you may need to use a range query.

Answer (score 1):

I convert the month year to YYYY-MM formate where it can be compared with the db.

```
$quer_mesano = "Select b.name AS Canal                                  
                from canal_canalvenda b
                inner join meta_meta c On  c.canal_canalvenda_id_c = b.id
                And c.deleted = 0
                where DATE_FORMAT( c.periodo, '%Y-%m' ) = '" . date("Y-m", strtotime($month_year)) . "' //Here is the date value I just need to put in month/year
                And b.deleted = 0
                Group by Canal order by 1";
```

Comment: I make sure both items are in the same format then comparing.